# Adding asynchronous code support to server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, task, task-parallel-library

I need to make some parallel code on my server side . I'm aware to the async feature in . Net 4.5 . 
But I need to implement it in . Net 4 . 
How can make the parallel code and wait till it finishes. Is there an example to do it with TPL library .
My server side is a Wcf service , I make calls to the db sequentially till get final result . These calls can be parallel and get all the data for short time .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Define server side. Need to be more clear on what what you want to do.    Parallel.Foreach blocks.

Comment: Questionis way too general. The Parallel class will be waht you want, which method(s) on it, no way to tell from this little information.

Comment: I have a Wcf service at the server side . I'm making calls to the database , I want to parallel the db calls so I can save time till get the final result .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create worker class:

```
public class AsyncClass
{
    public delegate void WorkFinishedDelegate();

    public event WorkFinishedDelegate WorkFinishedEvent;

    public void StartJob()
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadStart ts = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(DoSomeJob);
        System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(ts);
        //this will stast async thread...
        th.Start();
    }

    void DoSomeJob()
    { 
        //TODO: do your job


        //nofity you have completed...
        if (WorkFinishedEvent!= null)
        {
            WorkFinishedEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

Call your class:

```
        AsyncClass ac = new AsyncClass();
        ac.WorkFinishedEvent += new AsyncClass.WorkFinishedDelegate(ac_WorkFinishedEvent);
        ac.StartJob();

        void ac_WorkFinishedEvent()
        {
            //here you have been notified!
        }
```

Comment: I want this code on my Wcf service , so I need to wait till the worker finishes .

Comment: You can still use this code, you just need to create an loop. Here is how it it can be done: 1. add bool property HasFinished inside AsyncClass. 2. inside DoSomeJob method set HasFinished=true; 3. after calling ac.StartJob(); create while loop where you will wait until ac.HasFinished == true; 4. this is all you need :)

Answer (score 0):

For database ADO has asynchronous support.

[Asynchronous Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw97wx20.aspx)